# Revertendo o processo de uma função

Tags: funções, loop

Estava pensando em um projeto para teste de skills, sobre uma barra de carregamento e pensei, conseguimos desfazer uma modificação em uma página normalmente, mas e fazer o processo oposto ? por exemplo, temos um slideshow automático, a cada 1 segundo ele troca de imagem, sempre avançando, mas e quando chegamos ao fim do slideshow ? normalmente, ele volta todo o processo de uma única vez, jogando a gente de volta ao primeiro slide, mas e se, ao fim do slideshow, nós realizassemos o processo reverso, voltando a cada segundo, uma imagem, e ao fim dele, o processo recomeçasse, como isso poderia ser feito ?

EX:

preciso executar uma função repetidas vezes até chegar no objetivo, quando chegar no objetivo, preciso chamar outra função, que executará o inverso da anterior, que por sua vez, ao acabar, chamará a primeira função novamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça algo assim:

```
v_posicao_onde_estou : Integer
v_para_onde_estou_indo : Integer
v_quantide_de_slides : Integer;


function qual_slide : Integer
{
   if ( v_posicao_onde_estou < 0 ) 
        v_para_onde_estou_indo = 1
   else if ( v_posicao_onde_estou > v_quantidade_de_slides )  
       v_para_onde_estou_indo = -1

   v_posicao_onde_estou = v_posicao_onde_estou + v_para_onde_estou_indo;
   return v_posicao_onde_estou 

}

v_posicao_onde_estou = 0;
v_para_onde_estou_indo = 1;
v_quantide_de_slides = 100;


while ( true ) {
  mostra_slide ( qual_slide )
}
```

Comment: isso fará com que ao fim, ele fique revezando entre ultimo e penúltimo

Comment: Não. Veja que ele altera a direção apenas quando for menor que 0 ou maior que a quantidade de slides.